# Why is the text index search not working?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my collection, I have two documents like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e284b9ab13f4efa7472ac71"), "someText" : "Hi what are you doing" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e284b9ab13f4efa7472ac72"), "someText" : "HI there" }
```

I created a text index like:

```
db.users.createIndex({someText: "text"});
```

and when I search like this:

```
db.users.find({$text: {$search: "Hi"}});
```

since 'hi' is in both documents it's returning both as expected.

But this isn't working

```
db.users.find({$text: {$search: "there"}});
```

I'm expecting it to return the second document but it's not and the count is 0. Same behaviour when I search for 'what' or 'doing'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`there` is considered as one of the [stopwords](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt) used by MongoDB when full text search is build. You can use

```
{ default_language: "none" }
```

to prevent them from being ignored when index gets built ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#supported-languages-and-stop-words))

Comment: Looks like I picked the worst sentences :). Thanks for the link.